# Renaming Spark Dataframe Columns Python in Databricks

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark

I'm trying to assign column names to a large dataframe with 164 columns using the following command:

```
df.columns = [str(i) for i in range(len(df.columns))]
```

However, I get this error:

***AttributeError: can't set attribute***

I am doing this in a databricks cell, although I don't know whether that should have any effect on the code. Since I don't know what the column names should be (I have no schema to work with), I simply wanted to name each column based on its position. Can anyone help me set the column names to '0', '1', '2', etc.?

The dataframe was formed by spark.read.format("csv")

Comment: What is `type(df)` ? Is it a pandas data frame ?

Comment: @Psidom yes. It is a pandas dataframe

Comment: this should work for pandas but not spark. Your error will appear for a spark df. Are you sure you have a pandas dataframe?

Comment: @mck right, when reexaining my code it's a dataframe formed by spark.read.format("csv")

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify `df.columns` like in pandas, but you can select the columns and alias them as you wish:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.select([F.col(col).alias(str(idx)) for (idx, col) in enumerate(df.columns)])
```